# Third Party Authentication Oauth with Adapter Pattern Design

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ioc-container

I am writing a third party authentication method for facebook and google+ currently.

I decided to use adapter design pattern and this is my first time that I am following design patterns

Here is my design structure

```
namespace ThirdPartyRegister.Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class ThirdPartyRegister
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Login_Test()
    {
        IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter adapter= new ThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter(new GooglePlusAuthentication());

        var testResult = adapter.Login();
        Assert.IsFalse(testResult);
    }
}

public interface IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter{
    bool Login();
 }

public class ThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter : IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter
{
    private readonly IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter _thirdPartyAuthentication;

    public ThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter (IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter thirdPartyAuthentication){
         _thirdPartyAuthentication = thirdPartyAuthentication;
    }

    public bool Login()
    {
        return _thirdPartyAuthentication.Login();
    }

}

public class GooglePlusAuthentication : IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter{
    public bool Login()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class FacebookAuthentication : IThirdPartyAuthenticationAdapter{
   public bool Login()
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

}

My question is the approach applied above proper? Or did I miss something for adapter design pattern

Comment: "Right" is way to broad/opinion based. Are you asking if you implement adapter pattern right OR create useful interface OR use IOC container correctly OR something else?

Comment: I updated the question by clearing the question @AlexeiLevenkov